# Spring Security: Using BCryptPasswordEncoder inside custom authentication provide

Tags: spring-security

I have hashed my password like this:

```
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
```

Now how will i authenticate login username and password using custom spring authentication

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException{
```

}

Inside this how can i use `BCryptPasswordEncoder` to match if login password is correct or not

Answer (score 0):

The core of your authenticate method will probably look something like:

```java
String rawPassword = (String)authentication.getCredentials();
if (!passwordEncoder.matches(rawPassword, hashedPassword)) {
    throw new BadCredentialsException("Wrong password");
}
```

Comment: I chose to go with UserService